# How to query and return pydantic models in FastAPI

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I have a sqlalchemy model

```py
class Something(Base):
    __tablename__ = "something"

    an_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey("activities.id"))
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    age: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer)
    status: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean(), server_default=false())
```

I want to pick `age` and `status` from db and return the query response as a pydantic object (can be a list also)

The sqlalchemy query is added below

```py
db.query(Something.age, Something.status)
    .filter(Something.user_id.in_([1,2,3]))
    .order_by(desc(Something.an_id))
```

The response is a tuple of (age, status). I need a pydantic object to be returned

Comment: You're not going to get a better answer and explanations than what's already in the [tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/)

Comment: Just query for `Something` instead of selecting each column, and set `from_attributes` in your model_config so that the response model can load the values directly from the sqlalchemy object.

Comment: @PGHE Since the FastAPI documentation does not yet include the use of SQLModel, it is still possible to write a better answer. 

Comment: I am trying to avoid fetching all columns from db, what if my table has 20-30 columns and I just need two of them.

Comment: @JoseKaithakkary Have a look at https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/232#issuecomment-1026857814

Answer (score 0):

I recommand using [SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/) (from the same author than FastAPI) as it merges SQLAlchemy schemas with Pydantic schemas in a single Python class.

Here is an SQLModel example based on your proposed `SomeThing` schema:

```py
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field

class Something(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "something"

    an_id: int | None = Field(default=None, foreign_key="activities.id")
    user_id: int = Field(nullable=False)
    age: int
    status: bool = Field(default=False)
```

Here is the corresponding query that returns a list of Something objects (`List[Something]`) which are valid Pydantic models:

```py
from sqlmodel import Session, select

# assuming 'engine' is your SQLAlchemy engine
with Session(engine) as session:
    statement = select(Something)\
        .where(Something.user_id.in_([1, 2, 3]))\
        .order_by(Something.an_id.desc())
    somethings = session.exec(statement).all()
```